# Custom font iOS in Today Widget always return nil

Tags: ios, uifont, ios8-today-widget

I was trying to add custom font to my today extension but `UIFont` always return `nil`.

Steps:

1. I added the font file to Today Widget target:

[image]

2. I check if the font file was inside the Today Widget bundle:

[image]

3. I init the font instance in the `TodayViewController` of Today Widget but it always return `nil`:

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIFont* ft = [UIFont fontWithName:@"octicons-local" size:20];
}
```

[image]

I used the same method in my main project, and I can get the custom font. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe it's because you forgot to add key in your `.plist` file.

Add the key `Fonts provided by application` to a new row. Add items for each font you have added.

Comment: I think I don't have to add this key in new version of project,but I am wrong.Thank you .

Comment: Great! you solved your problem:) and you are welcome@wj2061

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and in my case adding full file name including file extension under the plist key `Fonts provided by application` worked for me. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem also, and I DID `targeting font to my target` and put `fonts providing by application` in plist. But still gets nil when I tried to retrieve font.

**Maybe because the font name you're using is wrong.**

**For Example** (**also the problem I met**)

The Font which I dragged into my project name is `trenolt.otf`

But Use this name `UIFont(name: "trenolt", size: 14)` gets nil

And According to [Adding a Custom Font to Your App By Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app)

I print out all the font familys and names

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames.sorted() {
  let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
  print("Family: \(family) Font names: \(names)")
}
```

Then I get in console

```
["TruenoLt", "TruenoRg"]
```

And now use the printed name

```
UIFont(name: "TruenoLt", size: 14)
```

Gets

```
<UICTFont: 0x7fbc39a168b0> font-family: "Trueno"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved by installing the fonts. So here are the steps:
Right click on your .otf file from Project Navigator-> Click on show in finder -> double click the font from the finder window and you will see "install" button in the bottom right corner, click on install and then check in your app.

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working on an app extension. Some answers here helped me to solve it, but I wanted to make it clear and maybe easier for other devs facing the same problem as I did:

While the Fonts were working in the App, they did not in the extension, which caused a crash because

```
UIFont(name: name.rawValue, size: size)
```

returned `nil`.

The fonts were in the `Info.plist` file of the app itself, but not in the `Info.plist` of the app extension. So I had to manually add a row to the extension's `Info.plist` with the key `Fonts provided by application` and enter all fonts of the app's `Info.plist` file until they matched. Then it worked for me.